# SQL Server Severe Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssis

I am executing a SQL Server Job that runs a set of SSIS packages.  The run time for a full file set is about 16 hours.

I am running SQL Server 2016 in an Azure environment.  The job the last two days has been finishing at 1 or 2 in the morning.  When I come in the next morning my job execution window is saying the job failed but when I go in to view the job history it says everything thing in the job ran successfully.  So I have no errors to go off of to try and figure this out except for these couples lines.
[image]

Is this truly an issue or is it more of just a bug?  I'm lost on where to proceed.

EDIT: Here is the job history.
[image]

Comment: Please show SSIS job execution report and SQL Server Agent Job History for more info.

Comment: What info you have in log? sysssislog or whatever the way you configured...

Comment: Clearly the job history does not say everything was successful ... what's in the detail?

Comment: Agree with above the job execution report will give more info. Another thing to check, i presume from the title the job is importing data, would be the destination tables you are expecting data to end up in. If you can compare input file to final output via a record count or something, even better, say if only a couple of records are missing it might be possible to track them down and check for invalid input data as a starting point

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the job history.

Comment: Do you have an error log on the Agent job? You can click the error button in left bottom corner to see detailed SQL error.